# text history on iphone 6

Tags: iphone, text

I thought you could go back to see entire history of texting from/between each person, any person. A couple of times I have seen back farther but usually not (am only looking to research one person at the moment). How do I get to the origin of that contact/trail and see them all with that particular person?

Comment: You can scroll back in the chat history within Messages. If this doesn't work for you or if you are using a different application, please add more details to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use iMessage? This is the best way to preserve text history, available even after restoring your device to factory settings.

Comment: You can also now use iCloud to save messages.